# Image failed when changing image source (a lot of images)

Tags: c#, wpf, image

My WPF application fails when I try to change the Image.Source of my Image container with a lot of images.

I have around 1440 images, and with a slider you can move between them.

So on the Value_Changed event the following code is being executed:

The application doesn't crash, but it simply doesn't show an image anymore (after +/- 1000). When I trigger the Image_Failed event I get a message.

My code:

```
            string imageNo = e.NewValue.ToString();
            string imagePath = "Resources/NetTVImages/nettv" + imageNo + ".png";
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imagePath, UriKind.Relative));
            overlayImage.Source = image;
```

Kind regards,
Niels

**EDIT:** I do not get a System Message, but just my MessageBox that triggers. So I know the Image_Failed event it triggered.

**EDIT2** Actually, I do get an exception:

System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\User\CPP\bin\Debug\Resources\Images\447.png'.

Comment: and what would that message that you get be?

Comment: I have put a MessageBox in side this event, so this triggers when the Image container fails. I have to put a dispatcher to let it trigger.

Is there a better way to load a large amount of images then the way I try to do it?

Comment: The [ExceptionRoutedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.exceptionroutedeventargs.aspx) passed to your ImageFailed handler has an [ErrorException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.exceptionroutedeventargs.errorexception.aspx) property that may tell you why loading failed.

Comment: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\User\CPP\bin\Debug\Resources\Images\447.png'.

Comment: @Niels That message says it all, right? Looks like the image file isn't there.

Comment: At least your code sets `imagePath = "Resources/NetTVImages/nettv"`, not `Resources/Images`.